# Create geo-referenced raster crossing dateline in Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, antimeridian

I am trying to create a geo-referenced raster from data that crosses the dateline. In one example my data runs from 11-69N, 150-210E. I am pretty new to both Python and creating rasters, but have successfully created them for datasets that stay within the -180 to 180 range using both Python gdal and rasterio. However, for all datasets I have that cross 180 my rasters either wrap the globe the long way around or, using EPSG 3832, are not referenced correctly and are nowhere near where they are supposed to be. Everything I can find on the forums related to this seems to be working with world-wide data sets.

What I have - I'm only going to show the versions that are working for data that does not cross the dateline. I have tried a lot of variations that did not help:

1 - very quick rasterio NetCDF to raster

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np

fpath = 'C:/data/prov_file.nc'

ds = nc.Dataset(fpath)

ds_prov = ds['prov']

#numpy array of your province data 
prov_array = np.array(ds_prov)

#create geotiff 
lon = np.array(ds['lon'])
lat = np.array(ds['lat'])

#This case is has lons all > 180 
result = np.where(lon > 180)
listOfCoordinates = list(result[0])
lon[listOfCoordinates] = lon[listOfCoordinates]-360

xres = lon[1]-lon[0]
yres = -1*(lat[1]-lat[0])
nlat = lat.size
nlon = lon.size

from rasterio.transform import Affine, from_origin

transform = from_origin(lon[0], lat[nlat-1], xres, yres)

ds_tif = rio.open('netcdf_to_geotif.tiff',
                   'w',
                    driver = 'GTiff',
                    height = nlat,
                    width = nlon,
                    dtype = prov_array.dtype,
                    count = 1,
                    crs = 'EPSG:4326',
                    transform = transform)
ds_tif.write(prov_array, 1)
ds_tif.close()
```

2 - Longer version using gdal and adding color map

```
create_gtif(output_file, lat, lon, prov):
    print('Creating ', output_file)
    result = np.where(lon > 180)
    listOfCoordinates = list(result[0])
    lon[listOfCoordinates] = lon[listOfCoordinates]-360
    del result

    nlat = lat.size
    nlon = lon.size

    xmin = lon[0]
    xmax = lon[nlon-1]
    ymin = lat[0]
    ymax = lat[nlat-1]
    xres = lon[1] - lon[0]
    yres = lat[1] - lat[0]

    prov_matrix = np.empty((nlat,nlon))
    prov_matrix = prov.filled(fill_value=32)

    collst = set_color_map()
    colarr = np.asarray(collst)
    colarr = np.vstack((colarr, [1, 1, 1, 1]))
    colarr = colarr * 255
    colarr = colarr.astype(np.int64)
    del collst

    geotransform = (xmin, xres, 0, ymax, 0, -yres)
    
    del xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, xres, yres

    # Create GeoTIFF
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
    dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file, nlon, nlat, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    del driver, nlat, nlon

    # Upper Left x, Eeast-West px resolution, rotation, Upper Left y, rotation, North-South px resolution
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
    del geotransform

    # Set CRS
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84")
    dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )
    del srs

    prov_matrix = np.flip(prov_matrix, 0)

    # Write the band
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(prov_matrix)
    del prov_matrix

    band = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    colors = gdal.ColorTable()

    for icol in range(colarr.shape[0]):
        colors.SetColorEntry(icol, tuple(colarr[icol]))
    del colarr, icol

    band.SetRasterColorTable(colors)
    band.SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_PaletteIndex)
    del band, dst_ds, colors
```

What do I need to do to create a geo-referenced raster that is in the Pacific and crosses 180?